# Using jars which have no dependency tag in Maven's pom.xml

Tags: maven, jar

I have a web application which needs to be converted to Maven for building and deploying. 
I was able to find dependency to add in pom for most of the jars but was not able to find dependency tag for few jar files.
How do I add these jars to my application so that my application compiles ?
Can I add these jars for Maven from web-inf/lib or some other location ?

Answer (score 0):

You can install jars manually to your maven repository using the maven-install-plugin:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, I do not know the groupid, artifactid, version of the jar, I only have those old jars with me which my applicaton needs. Can I specify groupid, artifactid and version of my choice ?

Comment: yes, you use `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>` and specify the Details yourself. Then the jar is installed in your local repo and can be referenced from Projects using that repo with the artifactId, Version, ... you provided yourself with the install command.